# No pagebreak before section that only contains added pdfs

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, pdfpages

In my report i have a last section that only contains spectra, which i add via `\includepdf[]{}`. Often there is a pagebreak before the section so there is an almost empty page with only the section title and then the added pdfs.
How do I prevent latex from making a pagebreak before this section if anyhow possible?

```
\section{Section}
Bla bla
\nopagebreak
\section{Spectra}
\pagebreak
\includepdf[angle=90]{spectra/dummyspectrum}
```

does sometimes work but it seems not in the current case...
I don't have a MWE because it would not be very "minimal" and if I put some dummy text instead it seems to work.
Hope in the picture one sees what the problem is.

[image]

edit: added "minimal" working example (still not complete Praeambula) that reproduces the issue.

It seems I also found a workaround. When adding

```
\FloatBarrier
\subsection{Massenspektrometrie}
```

then it works. But I have no clue why. Of course there is the float in the previous subsection (the big black box in the MWE). But wth should it prevent the next section title to be set on a page that oviously has enough whitespace available?
Also, it prevents the float to float past upcoming subsections which is totally fine in the current case but which is I do not really intend here.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[british,ngerman]{babel} %Letzte Sprache = Hauptsprache
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries} %Section Titel in Serifen
\setkomafont{caption}{\footnotesize\sffamily\bfseries}  %Captions in Serifenlos und fett
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\usekomafont{caption}}   %Text nach caption gleich wie caption
\usepackage{textgreek}  %Aufrechte griechische Buchstaben: upgreek, textgreek
\usepackage{color, lipsum, pdfpages}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[format=plain]{caption}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}   %Zeilenumbruch Abstand
\parskip=0.5\baselineskip   %Abstand zwischen Abschnitten
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
    modules={spectroscopy,scheme,isotopes},
    greek=textgreek,
    nomenclature/iupac = strict,
    }
\RenewChemIUPAC{\D}{\chemDelta}
\RenewChemIUPAC{\L}{\chemLambda}
\newcommand\question[1]{\noindent\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}\par}

%HEADER, FOOTER
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lohead{Baron von Tannenhausen}
\rohead{Experiment 3.14}
\lofoot*{}
\rofoot*{\pagemark\ von \pageref{LastPage}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\Huge Titlepage
\end{titlepage}

\section{Ziel des Versuchs}\lipsum[1]\section{Einleitung}\lipsum[1-2]\section{Experimentelle Durchführung}\lipsum[1-3]\section{Diskussion}\lipsum[1]\section{Schlussfolgerung}\lipsum[1]\bibliography{bibliography}\section{Beantwortung der Fragen}\subsection{Template Synthese}\lipsum[1]\subsection{Stabilität von Komplexen}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Isomerie}
\question{Welche Isomere existieren für die unten gezeigten Verbindungen? Zeichne die Strukturen aller Isomere und benenne sie.}

\begin{figure}[!hp]
%\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{images/question3-2}
\rule{0.7\textwidth}{0.6\textwidth} %NEWLY ADDED FOR MWE
\caption{1a: \ch{\L-[Rh(acac)3]}, 1b: \ch{\D-[Rh(acac)3]}, 2a: \ch{\cis-[PtCl2(PMe3)2]}, 2b: \ch{\trans-[PtCl2(PMe3)2]}, 3a: \ch{\fac-[TiCl3(THF)3)]}, 3b: \ch{\mer-[TiCl3(THF)3)]}, 4a: \ch{\cis-[IrClCO(PPh3)2]}, 4b: \ch{\trans-[IrClCO(PPh3)2]}, 5a: \ch{\L-[Fe(phen)3]^{2+}}, 5b: \ch{\D-[Fe(phen)3]^{2+}}, 6a: \ch{\cis-\L-[RuCl2(bpy)2]}, 6b: \ch{\cis-\D-[RuCl2(bpy)2]}, 6c: \ch{\trans-[RuCl2(bpy)2]}, 7: \ch{CoCl2Br2}; 8a: \ch{\L-[Cu(etbpy)2)]^{+}}, 8b: \ch{\D-[Cu(etbpy)2)]^{+}}.
}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Massenspektrometrie}
\question{Für Salze der Form \ch{[ML_{x}]X_{y}} (L = Ligand, \ch{X-} = Gegenion) ist es üblich, im Massenspektrum peaks für die Ionen \ch{[ML_xX_{y-1}]+}, \ch{[ML_xX_{y-2}]^{2+}}, usw. zu sehen. Die intensivste Gruppe an Peaks im Massenspektrum von \ch{[Co(en)3]Cl3} ist unten gezeigt. Cobalt hat nur ein Isotop. Erkläre das Muster der Peaks.}

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
%\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{images/question4}
\rule{0.8\textwidth}{1.2\textwidth} %NEWLY ADDED FOR MWE
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lp{1.2cm}X}
$m/z$   &   ca. Int. / \%   &   Zuordnung   \\ \hline\hline
309.1   &   100 &   Basispeak; \ch{C6H24^{35}Cl2CoN6}   \\
310.1   &   10  &   \ch{^{13}C^{12}C5H24^{35}Cl2CoN6}; ein \isotope*{12,C} durch \ch{13,C} ersetzt  \\
311.1   &   65  &   \ch{C6H24^{37}Cl^{35}ClCoN6} und \ch{^{13}C2^{12}C4H24^{35}Cl2CoN6}; ein \isotope*{35,Cl} durch \isotope*{37,Cl} erstzt oder zwei \isotope*{12,C} durch \isotope*{13,C} ersetzt \\
312.1   &   5   &   \ch{^{13}C^{12}C5H24^{37}Cl^{35}ClCoN6}; ein \isotope*{35,Cl} durch \isotope*{37,Cl} erstzt und ein \isotope*{12,C} durch \isotope*{13,C} ersetzt   \\
313.1   &   10  &   \ch{C6H24^{37}Cl2CoN6}; zwei \isotope*{35,Cl} durch \isotope*{37,Cl} erstzt \\
314.1   &   2   &   \ch{^{13}C^{12}C5H24^{37}Cl2CoN6}; zwei \isotope*{35,Cl} durch \isotope*{37,Cl} erstzt und ein \isotope*{12,C} durch \isotope*{13,C} ersetzt    \\
\end{tabularx}
\normalsize
Natürlich sind auch Isotope von Stickstoff und Sauerstoff vorhanden sowie Spezies mit mehr als zwei \isotope*{13,C}. Diese sind jedoch  vernachlässigbar unwahrscheinlich.
\end{minipage}

\nopagebreak
\section{Spektren}
\includepdf[angle=90]{spectra/dummy}
\includepdf[angle=90]{spectra/dummy}
\includepdf[angle=90]{spectra/dummy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would imagine that you  want `\clearpage` after `\section{Spectra}`

Comment: Well, that still puts the `\section{Spectra}` on an otherwise empty page while there is still way enough space left on the previous page.

Comment: if it does there is something stopping the section head going on the previous page but without any code pretty hard to guess why, I am assuming that you are using a document class where sections do normally start mid-page.

Comment: in particular the page before the heading looks like a figure but impossible to tell if it is a float page or a text page

Comment: i use `scrartcl`. Usually it works fine. If it doesn't it worked till now with `\nopagebreak`. The previous page page contains a minipage with an `\includegraphics[]{}` and a minipage with a `\tabularx`.

Comment: No sorry there are simply too many variables I could not guess an answer with just that amount of information. You should be able to make an example easily enough.  start from a copy of the document delete everything after the bad break and before the page befpre the bad break, and replace images by `\rule{2cm}{5cm}` or whatever size imitates the image.

Comment: of course understandable; i will see

Comment: @Wulfram [Check out this article for making a minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Yes, i do know what a MWE is. Just in this case there is many variables so i need to include anything that could possibly have any impact. I added it now. Also I found a workararound.

Comment: if you have an answer you should post the answer, no one else can run your example as you still reference files that are not available, so only ypu can answer really.

Comment: @David Carlisle Is there a way to add some "dummy pdf" or so? Like putting a black box with `\rule{}{}` instead of `\includegraphics[]{}`?

Comment: can't you just put a black box for that as well?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Nope. Not with `\includepdf{}`it seems. There are the options `\includepdf[draft]{}`and `\includepdf[demo]{}`but they still give an error if the pdf's are not present. Doesn't matter actually since it will still typeset the document.

Comment: no I mean remove includepdf and just use a \rule there instead

Comment: You can use e.g. \includepdf{example-image-a4} as a dummy.

Comment: the problem is because of `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` which mean that there is a `\FloatBarrier` (-> `\clearpage`) just before `\section{Spektren}`.

Comment: @touhami well, an unswered less :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX hope it will be accepted ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` because with this option the package redefine `\section` command by adding `\FloatBarrier` (`-> \clearpage`) before  the original definition.

Comment: So to prevent such behaviour I just put `\usepackage{placeins}` without the option `[section]` and put all the `\FloatBarrier` 's manually where needed?

Comment: @Wulfram exactly as far as i know.